# BREACH attack and content length

Tags: tls, web-browser, http

I've been researching BREACH, and while I can understand how it might work if you have access to the the browser (to send crafted requests) and the wire (to capture *compressed* response length), I haven't seen a way to do this without access to the wire, aside from a fragile timing attack on response time. You can get `Content-length` with this code, but it only works if the site enabled CORS and isn't used a chunked `Content-length`.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
```

There's also an `iframe` approach, but I'm not aware of a way to get the `Content-length` for an iframe, and again, this fails if it's chunked.

Am I missing something? I there a technique I haven't covered for getting the `Content-length`? It doesn't seem to be a viable attack without both access to the browser and access to either that, or to the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BREACH attack is a Side-Channel attack. You need some way to access the side channel.

[On page 13 of the presentation](https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/US-13-Prado-SSL-Gone-in-30-seconds-A-BREACH-beyond-CRIME-Slides.pdf#page=13), you can see what BREACH needs the attacker to set up:

1. A web server serving the site the browser visits.
2. A callback where the javascript on the victim's browser notifies the attacker that the request completed, giving time information about when the packets with the currently tried string went through.
3. A MITM for monitoring the length of the sent packets.

So, in other words, you need access to the wire.

Comment: But not just the side channel; you also need access to the browser? This might just mean a link the user opened, or maybe an injected `iframe` in an HTTP request (that's quite doable if you have access to the wire).

Comment: lots of side channel attacks base on plaintext-injection-like methods.

Comment: Isn't BREACH the least of your worries if there is a MITM? I mean, it seems like the requirements in order for this to be effective would leave to you open to much more sinister attacks. What am I missing?

Comment: In the context of the paper, MITM just means there is somebody that can read your encrypted traffic.